# 3dModel skeleton presentation in iOS application and its horizontal rotation 360 degree

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, 3d-model, iosdeployment

i have a ios application where i have to present 3dModel of the skeleton and rotate it horizontally 360 degrees. I have searched a lot but didn't reach to the solid lead, help will be appreciated.I am doing project in objectiveC

Comment: You can do this by adding Unity screen to the app. Present the skeleton on the Unity framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit).

Comment: i have to do it inside native mobile application in only one screen rest of them are normal mobile application

Comment: You still can use SceneKit. It is Apple framework designed for 3D scene management.